# Does redis KEYS operation affect LRU eviction policy

Tags: redis

I am wondering if using [KEYS](https://redis.io/commands/keys/) does affect the LRU eviction policy? Let's say I grab all the keys using `KEYS` command, does that count as all keys have been recently used thus resetting the LRU and in turn makes the eviction act almost randomly?

Read the documentation on redis, found no answers on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NO, it does NOT update LRU or LFU stats.

However, you should never use `KEYS` command in production environment, since it might block Redis for a long time.

Comment: > should never use KEYS command in production environment
Yup, SCAN should be used instead as redis is a single threaded

Thank you for your answer